# Replace spaces in certain positions

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a text file as below.

data.txt

```
12345678909876456    qwerty
1234567890987       qwerty
23456789011234567   qwerty
```

I want to show it in the below way.

1. It will replace from 11th position to 20th position.
2. It will replace all spaces with '0' in between that position.
3. And it should consider only replace line starts with 1234.

So far I am able to tokenize the string but not able to replace spaces properly.

```
sed 's/^1234\(.\{6\}\)\(.\{10\}\)\(.*\)/1234\1Hi\3/' data.txt
```

its giving me output as

```
1234567890Hi qwerty
1234567890Hiqwerty
23456789011234567   qwerty
```

Comment: Welcome, what should be the desired output?

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there...a slight change in your regex plus encasing the s/// in a do-while loop until there are no more spaces left in string position from 11 to 20.

```
sed -e '
  :loop
    s/^\(1234.\{6\}[0-9]\{0,9\}\) /\10/
  t loop
' file

12345678909876456000qwerty
12345678909870000000qwerty
23456789011234567   qwerty
```

Answer (score 3):

Some more approaches:

```
sed '
  /^1234/!b
  :1
    s/^\(.\{10,19\}\) /\10/
  t1' < file
```

```
perl -pe 'substr($_, 10, 10) =~ y/ /0/ if /^1234/' < file
```

```
perl -pe 's{^1234.{6}\K.{10}}{$& =~ y/ /0/r}e' < file
```

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='10 10 *' -vOFS= '
  /^1234/ {gsub(/ /, "0", $2)}; {print}' < file
```

(With `perl`, add the `-C` option or `-Mopen=locale` if the input is UTF-8 or is to be considered as being encoded in the locale's charmap instead of just a single-byte per character superset of ASCII).